# MySql Servers Connection

Tags: mysql

I have distributed database system course and it has a project which requires retrieving, inserting, and deleting data that are located in different servers so, I will deal with more than one server . I will have more than one server by using mysql server.

But, really I know how to deal with one server but now two servers I don't know :( how can I do it. 
please I need help here:(
thanks all in advance

Comment: I don't really appreciate it when folks downvote questions, but do keep in mind it's very important that you don't ask someone to do your homework for you. Try to show what work you have already accomplished, and where you're stuck :)

Comment: Tagged as ios? really?

Comment: @MillaresRoo Unnecessary statement, but pretty funny none the less :)

Answer (score 2):

I really don't like answering homework questions, but the idea here is rather simple.

First, grab a connection identifier to each db

```
$con1 = $mysqli = new mysqli($server1, $user1, $password1, $database1, $port1);
$con2 = $mysqli = new mysqli($server2, $user2, $password2, $database2, $port2);
```

Then, each time you need to query the separate servers, just pass in the connection in the appropriate argument position.

```
$result1 = mysqli_query($con1,$queryString1);
$result2 = mysqli_query($con2,$queryString2);
```

This is a very rudimentary example, so I'll leave using prepared statements up to you, which you should be using to escape and sanitize your strings. I will also leave result processing up to you, since this is a homework question.

mysqli_query has two versions, one where you just pass the query, and one where you pass a connection identifier before your query string. You might say it's for this exact situation :)

NOTE: Yes, I'm using both OO and procedural methods here, but it's to prove a point.

Comment: is this method works in case connecting with remote server? i read from website, that I should do some configuration on config.inc.php and add the information of the remote server but this method was not work i don't know why. any way you really help me thanks alot wish you all the best

note :
sorry for this misunderstanding but, i did all the things that are related to the project but i stuck on the remote connection. 

thanks again

Comment: @saraMB config.inc.php is going to be something relative to the project you're working on. I don't know what it looks like. With regards to a MySQL connection, you need to make sure your MySQL server is setup to accept connections from a different host. Honestly I think this should be a default (go ahead and start flaming folks) because most production setups have the DB as its own server, accepting remote connections. Anyway sara, take a look at this: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html

Answer (score 0):

You only need one connection per server:

```
$link1 = mysqli_connect("myhost1","myuser1","mypassw1","mybd1") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link1));

$link2 = mysqli_connect("myhost2","myuser2","mypassw2","mybd2") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link2));
```

And so on.